# select2 returning position of items, not ID of items

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm using a select2 to allow the user to select multiple options. Everything is working fine, except for one frustrating issue.

The first time I click the save button to save the items, it works. But then on subsequent calls, the ID of the items are replaced with the position of the items. For for example, if I have IDs 3, 6 and 10 selected, the first Save will work and 3,6,10 are passed to the controller.

But then if I reload the view and click save, the numbers 0,1,2 are passed in (ie, their relative positions in the select).

Here is the code:

Firstly, the HTML:

```
<select id="selectGroup" class="form-control" multiple="true">
```

On $(document).ready:

```
    // Load Groups
    $("#selectGroup").select2({ placeholder: 'Select' });
    $.ajax({
        url: ROOT_URL + "Group/GroupList",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {

            let dropdown = $('#selectGroup');
            dropdown.empty();
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', 0).text("(Select)"));
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, entry) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.GroupID).text(entry.GroupName));
            })

        },
        error: function (passParams) {
            Notify(passParams, "Unexpected Error Loading Groups", "error");
        }
    });
```

And finally the js for the save (called from a button which passes in the loanID):

```
function LoanGroupSave(loanID) {

    var grpIDs = '';
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#selectGroup :checked'), function (elm) {
        grpIDs += elm.value + ',';
    })

    var editURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/Loan/LoanGroupSave";
    //alert(editURL);

    var obj = { "LoanID": loanID, "GroupIDs": grpIDs };

    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: editURL,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            Notify("Group(s) information has been saved", "Saved", "success", false, "toast-top-right", 5000);
        }
        else {
            OpenPopupGeneral("Error(s)", response.message);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        OpenPopupGeneral("Unexpected Error(s)", "Error = " + errorThrown);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting for people who make the same mistake.

Problem was in my load - I needed to add the GroupID as the key, not the row number which was in the key parameter value:

```
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, entry) {
                var $newOption = $("<option selected='selected'></option>").val(entry.GroupID).text(entry.GroupName);
                $("#selectGroup").append($newOption).trigger('change');
            }
```